# How to use multi blocks with single tempaltes file in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I am overriding default.phtml and remove.phtml here by using core block but i need to use my custom block also.how do i achieve?

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default" as="default" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml">
       <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
             <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
          </block>
     </block>        
</referenceBlock>
```

like this

```
 <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default" as="default" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml">
       <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
             <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
             **<block class="Custom\Module\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.custom.actions.remove" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>**
          </block>
     </block>        
</referenceBlock>
```

basically i wanted to use 2 block classes for single remove.phtml file.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use viewModel instead of second block.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend the original class "Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" on your custom class, you'll be able to use both of them.

```
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove;

class MyCustomClass extends Remove {

  /**
   * @var Cart
   */
  protected $cartHelper;

  /**
   * @param Template\Context $context
   * @param Cart $cartHelper
   * @param array $data
   * @codeCoverageIgnore
   */

  public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    Cart $cartHelper,
    array $data = []
  ) {
    $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  //Your custom methods
}
```

If you still need to use more classes, use constructor-injection and add them to your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can create one custom class and you use two class depencity injection in the class constructor.

for example;

```php
<?php

namespace Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions;

class MyRemove extends Remove {
    protected $remove;
    protected $customRemove;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions $remove,
        Custom\Module\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove $customRemove;
    ) {
        $this->remove = $remove;
        $this->customRemove = $customRemove;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for these kind of problems.
so we can use view_model for appending other class without effecting existing one.
see the example here.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.custom.actions.remove">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\ViewModel\Cart\Items\Remove</argument>
        </arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

i put this into my layout file checkout_cart_index.xml
and created the Remove.php on Custom\Module\ViewModel\Cart\Items this location

Hope it will help to someone

Happy Coding !!